# User Profile Service Application Stuck in Provisioning

Tags: user-profile-service

My User Profile Service Application (NOT the synchronisation Service) stopped working so I deleted and tried to recreate it using PowerShell.

I have tried a number of times - deleting it before I start again (and the Databases).  Using the Central Administration deletion does not work so I use a mixture of `STADM -o deleteconfigurationobject -Id {ID of USer Profile Service Application}` and then a PowerShell script to delete the timer jobs.  (PowerShell `Remove-SPServiceApplication` fails with a The SPPersistedObject with id, {Id}, could not be found.)

I have tried creating the User Profile Service Application using Central Administration and using PowerShell (running under the \SP_Farm account so the schema on SYncDB is correct).There are no CRITICAL or UNEXPECTED items in the Logs.

The last relevant item in the ULS logs is a message saying it is waiting for a timer job to finish.

> "Waiting for service application instance provisioning job to complete
>   for service application with name 'User Profile Service' and type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.UserProfileApplication' "

The SPTimer service is still running.

I am running SP2013 with the September 2016 CU.

What am I missing ?

Comment: is ur farm admin account is in the Local admin on the server where you want to provision the UPA

Comment: yes it is. (the farm account is temporarily in the Local Administrators Group - I will remove it when I get this working)  Farm Account has Log on Locally rights as well

Comment: Make sure User profile service is running on one of the SharePoint server in the farm, before you start provision the UPS?

Comment: I have got not as far as the User Profile Synchronisation Service yet.  This is the User Profile Service Application.

Comment: Have you tried to start the upa instance(from central admin> manage services) first then try to provision it?

Comment: When I tried the CA route I did Service Applications -> New -> User Profile Service Application and filled in the blanks.  When I tried the PowerShell Route I used $upa = New-SPProfileServiceApplication -Name $upaName -ApplicationPool $saAppPoolName -ProfileDBName $upaProfileDBName -SocialDBName $upaSocialDBName -ProfileSyncDBName $upaSyncDBName

Comment: that is fine, but before this go to central admin > system settings > manage service on server....select the server where you want to provision the UPA then start the User profile service....once started then try to provision it

Comment: I got the same result - 25 minutes later - has not come back to me yet

Comment: How many servers in the farm?

Comment: Just the one server

Comment: Couple of things, I would try...clear the config cache and reboot the server then try again.also from central admin in timer job page if their is any one time job exist for upa related

Comment: Cleared config cache and rebooted.  When came to reprovision User Profile Service Application - same problem.  The timer job gumming up the works is "Service Application Instance Provisioning Job" for the UserProfileService.  This is the next to last ULS Log Entry :- SPTimerJobAsyncResult '237a1fca-7af8-4c9f-a268-8becac3b258d': SPTimerJobAsyncResult.End() invoked.   This is the last ULS entry :- SPTimerJobAsyncResult '237a1fca-7af8-4c9f-a268-8becac3b258d': Timer job has not completed.

Comment: that is really bizarre, have you tried to set the logging to verbose and then examine the ULS logs? i would also try to re run the config wizard with default settings and try again

Comment: PSConfig Wizard run successfully - still wading through ULS Logs - still same result.

Comment: THis is the output from the UL:SViewer :-

Answer (score 0):

THis is the output from the UL:SViewer :-

> User Profile Application 'User Profile Service Application'
>   installation complete.     Updating SPPersistedObject
>   SPServiceApplicationInstanceProvisioningJobDefinition Name=User
>   Profile Service Application. includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  Updating SPPersistedObject
>   SPServiceApplicationInstanceProvisioningJobDefinition Name=User
>   Profile Service Application. Version: 266128 Ensure: False, HashCode:
>   13459742, Id: 5bc277d5-fe58-4b55-9f7b-2380815be9ff, 
>   SPTimerJobAsyncResult '5bc277d5-fe58-4b55-9f7b-2380815be9ff': Created
>   SPTimerJobAsyncResult. SPTimerJobAsyncResult
>   '5bc277d5-fe58-4b55-9f7b-2380815be9ff': SPTimerJobAsyncResult.End()
>   invoked. SPTimerJobAsyncResult '5bc277d5-fe58-4b55-9f7b-2380815be9ff':
>   Timer job has not completed.  Blocking until job completes Blocking
>   until timer job '5bc277d5-fe58-4b55-9f7b-2380815be9ff' has completed.
>
> 20 minutes later
>
> SPTimerJobAsyncResult '5bc277d5-fe58-4b55-9f7b-2380815be9ff': An error
>   occurred while waiting for completion:
>   System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SharePoint.StackExchange Nigel Price. You have posted a new question in the answer field, and I would advise you to ask a new question instead. Use the "Ask Question" button in the upper right corner. You can always find out more in the [Help Section](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/asking).